# Setting up my own network inside room and connect with common router

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, switch, wired-networking

**Background and Specs**

I'm currently planning to add a personal network inside my room because of several reasons. However to do that, I thought to buy my own router and setup inside room and connect that to Ethernet wall port of the room. Also my [Synology DS218j NAS](https://www.synology.com/en-global/products/DS218j) will be connected with my personal network. This is the story inside room.

When it comes to outside, there are 4 rooms including mine where having one ethernet port for each room is a must. So I thought to use

1. CAT6 cables for inside the walls and wall to device connectivity
2. Common router ([TP-Link W8951ND](https://www.tp-link.com/no/products/details/cat-5030_TD-W8951ND.html) provided by ISP) - Does not support Gigabit ethernet (Max: 150Mbps)
3. 5 port switch (Still Undecided the model)
4. Another router for my room (Still Undecided the model)

**Problems**

So I have few problems and will state and describe them below.

1. My internet connection is more like 20Mbps. So using ISP provided internet router is enough to access the internet. But when it comes to my room router, to be able to communicate in maximum speed with [Synology DS2018j](https://www.synology.com/en-global/products/DS218j), it's better to have a Gigabit connectivity. So gigabit router is necessary I think. So my question is, is my conclusion correct? With this setup, would I be able to access 20Mbps internet and high speed gigabit connectivity inside my room?
2. Can you kindly recommend a router for my personal network and a 5 port switch for this setup?
3. I have to setup home network as well. So as I explained earlier, above stated devices will be used. But my ISP provided router does not provide an "`Uplink port`" (Router LAN ports are labeled as LAN1, LAN2, LAN3 and LAN4. Not Uplink). So how can I setup one (If necessary) and connect with switch ?
4. Is there an additional setup should I do when I connect My Router -> Switch -> ISP provided router.

Answer (score 1):

> Common router (TP-Link W8951ND provided by ISP) - Does not support Gigabit ethernet (Max: 150Mbps)

The "150 Mbps" is for 802.11n Wi-Fi – its Ethernet ports are 100 Mbps.

> But when it comes to my room router, to be able to communicate in maximum speed with Synology DS2018j, it's better to have a Gigabit connectivity. So gigabit router is necessary I think.

No; strictly speaking, the router is only relevant to communications *between* networks. All traffic within the same network (subnet) takes a shortcut **directly** through the Ethernet switch (the LAN1-4 ports in your router are actually an integrated switch).

So if your router doesn't have Gigabit ports, that's not a problem – buy an external Ethernet switch that does. Same-subnet communications will always take the shortest path through the switches. *(Simplified, but it's a good start.)*

> But my ISP provided router does not provide an "Uplink port" (Router LAN ports are labeled as LAN1, LAN2, LAN3 and LAN4. Not Uplink). So how can I setup one (If necessary) and connect with switch ?

The ISP-provided router probably expects the uplink to be from e.g. ADSL – not Ethernet. It's possible that it won't support any other configuration except for the exact customer that it was provided for in the first place.

It's also possible that the uplink port is simply labelled "WAN".

**In general,** if you wanted to reuse the router for a different configuration than it was originally provided for, the steps depend *very much* on the router's model, and how flexible its firmware is.

1. Since all the LAN1-4 ports most likely belong to the same internal switch, the firmware needs the ability to separate one of them – it could mean removing it from a 'bridge', it could mean setting up a new 'VLAN' just for that port, it could mean changing the port's 'master port' setting... It is impossible to say without knowing the device's model, and even then very difficult without having tried to do so myself.
2. Once the port is separate Ethernet-wise, the router should allow you to configure IP parameters for it separately as well. For example, you should be able to run a DHCP client on that port (or on its VLAN), and enable SNAT (masquerading) between the two networks.

> Is there an additional setup should I do when I connect My Router -> Switch -> ISP provided router.

To be able to receive packets *back* from the Internet, you need one of the two:

- In the ISP-provided router, configure a 'static route' for your personal subnet – specifying your own router's IP address as the "gateway".
- In your own router, enable SNAT (masquerading). This is actually enabled by default on most home routers.

Usually you won't need to do anything, because most home routers will have NAT enabled by default (and sometimes even permanently). But it's not the cleanest option in terms of networking – disabling NAT and configuring a static route would for example make 'port forwarding' through the two routers much simpler.

Comment: Thank you for great explanation. So using a 150Mbps router in my room will give me the gigabit internal speed? I'm not connecting my NAS with Switch. I need to connect it with my room router. Secondly, ISP router does not have a WAN port either :( .

Comment: Then connect it to your room router _through_ a switch, because you won't get gigabit speed out of 100 Mbps ports.

Comment: Yeah. So without getting a switch, is it possible if I get a gigabit router for my room? What would be the drawbacks?

Comment: There isn't much of a difference. Just the cost, and the number of Ethernet ports.